# How do I return results to several cells?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Excel sheet to be filled with three results:

[image]

I have the following code (simplified to explain my problem):

```
Public Function addieren(X, Y, Z, value) As Double
' function to calculate three results
' and to write these in three fields starting with
' the field calling the macro
Xa = X + value
Ya = Y + value
Za = Z + value

addieren = Za
End Function
```

The current version of course writes Xa to the field. How can I manage to write the three resulting values into three subsequent cells, starting with the one calling the function?

Comment: You can't, *and shouldn't*, use a function to change the value of any other cell except the cell that has the function. This should operate more or less the same as any work sheet function. There is a reason Microsoft did not write any equations that can alter other cells

Comment: hm – and how about the need for populating more then the calling cell?
I don't recap the english term for the function: selecting several cells and entering a formula by hitting “cmd-enter” (Excel Mac) populates several fields

Comment: You are looking for the word Array formula

Answer (score -1):

```
    Z = Z + value
    addieren = Z
End Function
```

The reason for returning only one value in your code seems to be the line “addieren = z” as the returned value equals the result of that equation. But how about the remaining result values for Y and X? 
also not working: I tried the array method when entering the formula (having three cells activated and hitting cmd-Enter). In that case I get three values but not based on the proper input values (shifted by one column each).